# How to correctly use X509Store?

Tags: c#

I've been using `X509Store` and his friends, `X509Certificate2` and `X509Certificate2Collection`. Everything was fine, but I've started to write tests for my code, and I've run into a problem. I generate a new test cert and install it to start each test, then remove the test cert at the end. The test certificates are non-deterministically not valid, despite having creation dates a day in the past and expiry dates a day in the future.

I've noticed that running a full GC and waiting for finalizers in TearDown fixes the tests.

I've been digging into the reference source here. It seems that `X509Certificate2` needs to be disposed, otherwise operations that already returned success (like adding to a store) can have not been flushed to the actual store (this is a behaviour of the Windows API, see `CertCloseStore` `CRYPT_E_PENDING_CLOSE` result).

It further seems that `X509Certificate2Collection` is basically just a `List<X509Certificate2>`, so every time such a list of certs is created, every single instance needs to be disposed, such as reading the `Certificates` property on the store.

Furthermore, when the `Find` method is used, this involves creating a temporary store, adding the certs, and then reading the certs back out again from unmanaged code, creating a new collection of certs which *also* all need to be disposed.

Is this really the correct way to use the `X509Store`? It seems to be unbelievable that the .NET API would be so tremendously unsafe and difficult to use correctly with silent failures and completely undocumented failure modes everywhere. Am I just missing something obvious or should these classes all be avoided?

Comment: [It says so in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store(v=vs.110).aspx): `Starting with the .NET Framework 4.6, this type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly.`.

Comment: Can't you just use `using`?

Answer (score 0):

What undocumented failure modes? You're supposed to dispose every single disposable object you own. This applies especially when you *know* you're dealing with native code. This is nothing specific to the certificate interfaces - files work the same way, database transactions work the same way, sockets work the same way. That's why the `IDisposable` interface exists in the first place - it's the common interface saying "call me when you're done". Did you stop using file I/O when you realized you're required to *close* the file? Or haven't you noticed that it's required yet?

The whole cryptography module that deals with SChannel is little more than a thin wrapper on top of SChannel. That is, almost every single thing you do is native interop, managed wrappers over native objects etc.

But it doesn't matter what the exact problem is. The key point is still that you're supposed to dispose disposables, always. Just because things seem to kind of work even if you don't doesn't mean it's fine to omit disposing objects.

Comment: Yeah, but I *don't* own them. I just read a property on the store. That doesn't indicate that I suddenly own a copy of every cert in the store. And the Find method absolutely does not suggest that I suddenly own yet another copy. The interface doesn't indicate in the slightest that I'm supposed to take ownership of these things, or even that any resources were created. Not to mention how this was supposed to be used prior to .NET 4.6. Or like, any kind of checking for the horrible "operations that succeeded randomly didn't happen" kind of thing. The collection itself isn't even Disposable.

Comment: @Puppy Well, you need to read the documentation. The store is supposed to be closed (`You should always close an X.509 certificate store after use.` all the way since .NET 2.0 docs), and the `Close` method has been there since the very beginning. Sure, it was an oversight to not include `IDisposable` on the store originally. But I still find it interesting that you don't consider the horrible "operations that succeeded randomly didn't happen" in every other scenario I mentioned (and there's plenty I didn't mention). .NET only gives you guarantees on *managed* objects; X509 store isn't managed.

Comment: In all of those other cases, correctness doesn't depend on disposing *other* objects that you never intended to create and nobody ever said were created.

Comment: @Puppy But you never have to do that. That's what `Close` (and now `Dispose`) does. Or are you trying to say that `Close` on the certificate store doesn't help?